# npm install always installing in the same directory and not to current directory

Tags: npm, npm-install, angular11

I am facing really a weird issue.

when i try to run the command 'npm install' it always installs in a different directory.

eg: i have the package.json in C:\Folder1\ and when i try to run 'npm install' it installs in C:\Folder2\

I tried running the command

'`npm config list`'

it always shows the '`cwd: C:\Folder2\`' as the current working directory

How can i change the cwd path so it works wherever the package.json exists.

Same code work for other developers correctly. this behavior is only happending in one of the machine

Thanks

Comment: what in your package.json? please add in the question to help you better.

Comment: What is the output of `npm config list`?